# Jupyter does not recognize Python Mac OSX (Kernel error)

Tags: python, macos, unix, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed python 3.6 with Anaconda, but after launching the jupyter notebook I cant use python.

When I launch a new notebook, I see 'Kernel Error' at the top of the page, with the following lines:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 75, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
 File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 94, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 257, in start_kernel
    **kw)
 File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 203, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python'
```

I guess that the last line is the key to solve this problem but I didnt find any soltuion relative to it as well.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels/issues/55

Comment: May be the link https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/147 is helpful.

Comment: i tried to run 'jupyter kernelspec list' but I have jupyter command not found,  I also tried 'pip install jupyter' and I get: -bash: pip: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work around:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
conda create -n py33 python=3.6 anaconda
source activate py33
python -m ipykernel install --user
```